# Cannot kinit nfs/ principal

Tags: debian, kerberos, nfsv4, samba4

I'm trying to mount a NFSv4 share but the `mount` command cannot get permissions to mount the share.

When I try to mount a share I receive the message:

```
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
```

And if I try to kinit the nfs principal with:
`kinit -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab nfs/nfshost.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM`
it returns:

```
kinit: Client 'nfs/nfshost.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials
```

Here's all the details on how I'm trying to configure and test the service. All hosts are Debian 12:

in the NFS server:
`/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
172.17.0.10 nfshost.domain.com nfshost
...
```

`/etc/krb5.conf` file

```
[libdefaults]
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  dns_lookup_kdc = false
  default_realm = DOMAIN.COM
  default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
  default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
  default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
  allow_weak_crypto = 0

[realms]
  DOMAIN.COM = {
  kdc = 172.17.0.20
  master_kdc = 172.17.0.20
  default_domain = domain.com
  admin_server = 172.17.0.20
  }

[domain_realm]
domain.com = DOMAIN.COM
.domain.com = DOMAIN.COM
```

`/etc/exports` file

```
/exports         172.17.0.0/16(rw,sync,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,crossmnt,sec=krb5)
/exports/users   172.17.0.0/16(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5)
```

`/etc/idmapd.conf` file

```
[General]
Verbosity = 0
Domain = domain.com

[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup

[Translation]
Method = nsswitch
```

`/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` file

```
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids"
NEED_SVCGSSD="yes"
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS=""
```

`/etc/default/nfs-common` file

```
NEED_STATD=no
STATDOPTS=
NEED_IDMAPD=yes
NEED_GSSD=yes
```

Commands to add the NFS server entry into the domain (AD Samba)

```
# kdestroy
# kinit administrator
# msktutil delete --computer-name NFSHOST --server 172.17.0.20
# msktutil -c -b "CN=COMPUTERS" -s HOST/nfshost.domain.com -h nfshost -k /etc/krb5.keytab --computer-name NFSHOST --server 172.17.0.20 --dont-expire-password --verbose --enctypes 28
```

in AD (Samba at 172.17.0.20):
add the following SPN's to the NFS server host added:

```
# samba-tool spn add nfs/nfshost NFSHOST$
# samba-tool spn add nfs/nfshost.domain.com NFSHOST$
# samba-tool spn add RestrictedKrbHost/nfshost NFSHOST$
# samba-tool spn add RestrictedKrbHost/nfshost.domain.com NFSHOST$
```

Check the NFS server host entry with `samba-tool computer show nfshost`:

```
dn: CN=NFSHOST,CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
objectClass: computer
cn: NFSHOST
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20230901104446.0Z
uSNCreated: 202585
name: NFSHOST
objectGUID: 305c91e0-328d-47f4-ab30-7a4c0ea951dc
badPwdCount: 0
codePage: 0
countryCode: 0
badPasswordTime: 0
lastLogoff: 0
lastLogon: 0
pwdLastSet: 133380386868301530
primaryGroupID: 515
objectSid: S-1-5-21-2898533208-202842514-1397044296-107323
accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
logonCount: 0
sAMAccountName: NFSHOST$
sAMAccountType: 805306369
objectCategory: CN=Computer,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
isCriticalSystemObject: FALSE
dNSHostName: nfshost.domain.com
msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes: 28
userAccountControl: 69632
servicePrincipalName: HOST/nfshost.domain.com
servicePrincipalName: host/nfshost
servicePrincipalName: nfs/nfshost
servicePrincipalName: nfs/nfshost.domain.com
servicePrincipalName: RestrictedKrbHost/nfshost
servicePrincipalName: RestrictedKrbHost/nfshost.domain.com
whenChanged: 20230901104626.0Z
uSNChanged: 202594
distinguishedName: CN=NFSHOST,CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Generate the NFS host keytab:

```
# samba-tool domain exportkeytab --principal=nfs/nfshost.domain.com keytab.NFSHOST-nfs
```

Back in the NFS server:
Retrieve the generated keytab from the AD:

```
scp root@172.17.0.20:/root/keytab.NFSHOST-nfs .
```

Merge it into the `/etc/krb5.keytab` file:

```
# ktutil
   rkt /etc/krb5.keytab
   rkt /root/keytab.NFSHOST-nfs
   wkt /etc/krb5.keytab
   quit

# chmod 600 /etc/krb5.keytab
# chown root:root /etc/krb5.keytab
```

Check if the SPN's are there:
`klist -kte /etc/krb5.keytab | grep nfs/nfshost.domain.com` returns several of:

```
1 01/09/2023 07:59:33 nfs/nfshost.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
1 01/09/2023 07:59:33 nfs/nfshost.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

Restart some services

```
exportfs -rav
/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
/etc/init.d/nfs-common restart
mount --bind /home/users /exports/users
```

Clocks between AD and the NFS server are in sync.
Hosts in the same VLAN, no firewall between both and no firewall inside anyone.

To the tests:

Try to mount a share (still in the NFS server)
`mount -t nfs4 nfshost.domain.com:/users /mnt -o sec=krb5 -v` returns:

```
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Fri Sep  1 08:03:22 2023
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4,addr=172.17.0.10,clientaddr=172.17.0.10'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting nfshost.domain.com:/users
```

Try to kinit the nfs principal:
`kinit -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab nfs/nfshost.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM` returns:

```
kinit: Client 'nfs/nfshost.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials
```

`/var/log/syslog` file have several of:

```
Sep  1 08:03:25 nfshost rpc.gssd[111218]: ERROR: No credentials found for connection to server nfshost.domain.com
```

What I'm missing to correctly configure this NFS service?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something with the `/etc/krb5.keytab` file, removing that file instead of doing `kdestroy`, and after the remaining procedures, the mount was successful.

I removed that file because it looked like it was too big (+2M) and taking too long to merge keytabs with `ktutil`.

I mistakenly thought that the `kdestroy` job was to clean the `/etc/krb5.keytab` file but, as stated by the `man 1 kdestroy`, his function is:
"The kdestroy utility destroys the user's active Kerberos authorization tickets by overwriting and deleting the credentials **cache** that contains them."

Comment: 2 MB?? That keytab must have had some ~24000 entries in it...